# Image Optimize using PageSpeed

Tags: image, optimization, opencart

I have scan my website grade using GTmetrix and PageSpeed insights and i have a problem about cache image, i  tried to replaced the suggested image given by them but every time i scanned my website there are the same scanned images in optimize images.

the example of image is like this

https://mycoffeelab.ph/image/cache/catalog/images/Banners/coffee-labbanner-1920x502.jpg

you can try to scan my site and here is the link mycoffeelab.ph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **delete** all files & folders inside `/image/cache` (except `index.html`).
Then Opencart will generate the new cached files based on the new images you have uploaded.